# Calculate service date of a truck with time and service day data

Tags: t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2005

We have some trucks that serve some destinations in different days. In Sql Server table, the table is like below.

```
TruckCode ServiceHour Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday      
Route1    17:00       1       0      1         0        1       0
Route2    09:30       1       1      1         1        1       1
Route3    14:30       0       1      0         1        0       0
```

Explanation of this table,
Route1 truck is serving on Monday,Wednesday,Friday and the serving time is 17:00.
Route2 truck is serving on every day and the serving time is 09:30.
Route3 truck is serving on Tuesday,Thursday and the serving time is 14:30.

I have order dates, and these orders have truck code and order time. I want to calculate the date and time when the order will be served. On Sunday, there is no serving.

For example, an order which order time is 17:05, order day is Monday and truck code is Route1, this will be served on Wednesday at 17:00. Because, Tuesday is not a serving day for Route1 and time is 5 minutes passed on Monday.

I am working on a solution based on charindex, like below.

I join day data into one string like, for example Route1, `10101001010100` , this represents, first char is 1 then this Route is serving on Monday, second char is 0 then this Route is not serving on Tuesday etc.

And i get the daynumber with `((datepart(dw,@orderInsertDate) + @@DATEFIRST-2) % 7+1)`

And charindex function is:

```
CHARINDEX('1','10101001010100',((datepart(dw,@orderInsertDate) + @@DATEFIRST-2) % 7+1)+
(case when ServeTime < getdate() then 1 else 0 end)
)
```

I need to compare the time as well, because, for example, a Route1 order which inserted at 16:30 on Monday is serving the same day, but an order which inserted at 17:30 on Monday is serving next Wednesday. Still couldn't manage to calculate the right value but i think the charindex will solve it.

How to calculate that?

Thanks from now.

Comment: May we see your attempt at solving the problem? Any research? Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: i tried a solution with a table variable, getting the week day number of order date, and a while loop in sql calculating the serve date and insert it into table variable, then select min date from that table which date is bigger than the order date. the second way i am now trying is charindex. i am joining the day numbers into one char like (10101010001) and get the weekday of order date, for today it is 1 because it is monday. and use charindex which searcing first 1 value starting order date weekday, like CHARINDEX('1','1010101001',@weekDay). i am working on charindex now.

Comment: we have Sql Server 2005, this is second comment because of comment string size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires normalized data but I think it works. Trust me that is it worth normalizing the data.

It does not wrap to the next week but you could check for null and wrap to the first delivery.

```
declare @R table (id int identity primary key, name varchar(20), tm time not null);
insert into @R (name, tm) values ('Route1', '17:00');
declare @D table (fk int, d tinyint not null);
insert into @D (fk, d) values (1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 6);

declare @dd int = 2;
declare @tt time = cast('17:05' as time);
select top (1) 
       r.name, r.tm, d.d, @dd as dOr, @tt as tOr 
from @R r 
join @D d
  on d.fk = r.id 
where r.id = 1 
  and  d.d > @dd 
   or (d.d = @dd and r.tm >= @tt)
order by d.d;

name                 tm               d    dOr         tOr
-------------------- ---------------- ---- ----------- ----------------
Route1               17:00:00.0000000 4    2           17:05:00.0000000
```